# Python lambdas and threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, lambda, python-3.9

Consider the following code:

```py
from threading import Thread

def foo(s):
   print(s)

d = {}
for s in ["a", "b"]:
   fun = lambda: foo(s)
   d[s] = Thread(target=fun)

[worker.start() for worker in d.values()]
```

I would expect that the lambda expression can not be changed after it got constructed, hence one of the threads needs to print an `a`, but that is not happening. Both threads are printing `b`. What IS happening here? What needs to be changed to have workload `a` included?

Comment: "I would expect that the lambda expression can not be changed after it got constructed" <- It does not. What changes is where the name `s` points to. After the loop `s = 'b'`.

Comment: You would see the same behavior with "normal" functions btw. Put a `def fun(): foo(s)` inside the loop to see for yourself.

Comment: ... And also without threads...

Comment: It does!  Thank you very much. 

The solution is to change the lambda too

`fun = lambda s=s: foo(s)`
This way the name `s` is not reused from the outer scope.